# runtimeExcpetion android

Tags: android, exception, logcat

i can't understand what is wrong with this code, and why is thrown this exception,below there are my main.xml and the logcat.

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.testing.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.fotech.closeups.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testing.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

mainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000;

    private Button showBtn;
    private GoogleMap map = null;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private Location myLocation;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private Display display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showBtn);
        showBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        showBtn.setClickable(false);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        display = new Display(map);

        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL).setSmallestDisplacement(10);

        if (locationClient != null)
            locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location listener called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng newPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        myLocation = location;
        if (myLocation != null)
            showBtn.setClickable(true);
        else
            showBtn.setClickable(false);

        display.clearMap();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newPosition, 16));
        display.addMarker(newPosition, "My Title", "..and my comments go here");
        display.setCircleOnMap(newPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Locationclient Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.showBtn) {
            if (InternetStatus.getInstance(this).isOnline(this)) {
                new ShowCloseUps(display, myLocation).execute();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(this, "No internet connection find one and retry!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (locationClient.isConnected() && locationClient != null) {
            locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            locationClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <Button 
          android:id="@+id/showBtn"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:text="@string/show"
          />

      <fragment 
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_above="@id/showBtn"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
              map:cameraZoom="5"
              map:cameraTilt="30"
              map:uiCompass="false"
              map:uiRotateGestures="true"
              map:uiTiltGestures="true"
              map:uiZoomGestures="true"
              />
</RelativeLayout>
```

my logcat tab:

```
   E/AndroidRuntime(1820): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testing/com.example.testing.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
    E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
   E/AndroidRuntime(1820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
  E/AndroidRuntime(1820):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1820):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

thanks for your collaboration.

Comment: post your **MainActivity** code...

Comment: @olrC in your xml file replace `.Main` with `.MainActivity`

Comment: @PRAKASHUBHADIYA already done before post question,but this didn't fix the error

Comment: @oIrC Now post your manifest.xml file

Comment: put this xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" at the top layout and remove it from the Fragment XML , change the android:name to class=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `minsdk="14"`. you need to used `MapFragment` instead of `SupportMapFragment`

```
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

and also extends `MainActivity` extends `Activity`

and also try to get map using

```
  map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: this line doesn't work: map = `((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`